# Utilizar data ou class para consultar elementos DOM

Tags: javascript, css

Aqui estou eu precisando de uma ajudinha para ter uma visão mais ampla sobre este assunto.

Por via de regra eu costumo evitar a utilização de `class` para consultar elementos no HTML, para isto acabo por utilizar uma `custom data property`.

em muitos casos acabo por ter duplicações no html:

```
<div data-content="" class="content" />
```

onde o meu CSS seria algo assim:

```
.content { ... }
```

E para consultar este elemento no JS faria algo assim:

```
var content = document.querySelectorAll("[data-content]");
```

Meu intuito aqui é manter separado a camada de apresentação da de comportamento, para que uma alteração no layout da pagina não afete os scripts e vice-versa.

Então gostaria de ouvir os pontos positivos e negativos desta abordagem? até aceito um JSPerf comparando `querySelectorAll` com o `getElementsByNameClass`

Comment: Você está partindo do princípio de que `class` só se refere à classe CSS correspondente? Na verdade não, as classes servem para complementar a semântica dos elementos, e agrupá-los em conjuntos com características comuns. Partindo desse conceito, é totalmente válido usar as classes como seletores também no JS.

Comment: De forma alguma, é mais uma questão de estilo de conveniência do que de limitação.

Comment: Apenas para complementar, a própria especificação da W3C deixa claro que class não se limita apenas a estilo, apenas acho inconveniente misturar o 'style' com o 'behavior'. Note: Assigning classes to an element affects class matching in selectors in CSS, the getElementsByClassName() method in the DOM, and other such features.

There are no additional restrictions on the tokens authors can use in the class attribute, but authors are encouraged to use values that describe the nature of the content, rather than values that describe the desired presentation of the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partindo do principio que estamos buscando por atributo, eu acredito que isso é mais lento, pois irá verificar todos os elementos da página, que podem possuir esse atributo.

Assim, buscar por `tag` ou fazer um `seletor` talvez fique mais rápido.

Ultimamente estou utilizando `custom data property.` para atributos dinâmicos, isso realmente torna muito mais fácil a manipulação dos elementos independente do comportamento.

Mas acredito que um teste de performance possa ajudar a tirar esse dúvida com certeza.

Comment: Luan, realmente uma busca por Id é praticamente 10x mais rápida que por className, que por sua vez é mais rápida um QuerySelectorAll, mas mesmo este último é capaz de realizar 7.000 operações por segundo, então isto seria um problema apenas em páginas muito grandes com consultas muito amplas.

Answer (score 1):

Em termos conceituais a resposta não precisa ser longa.

Se você utiliza `classe` ou até mesmo `custom data property`, o interpretador vai buscando elemento por elemento até achar todos os que batem com o seu seletor. Ou seja, **todos os elementos do seu documento são analisados**.

No caso do `custom data property` a situação é mais **lenta** pois além de analisar os *elementos*, o interpretador analisa também todas as *propriedades* desses elementos.

Se vocẽ tem um certo comportamento para **um grupo e elementos**, acredito em termos de `performance`, utilizar **class** é o mais indicado. Em termos de *legibilidade* concordo que o `property` é muito mais robusto aos olhos.

> Se seu documento não for tão grande acredito que valhe sim sacrificar
>   um pouco da performance e utilizar `property`. Não afetará mais que
>   alguns milisegundos que não resultarão em nada muito perceptível a seu
>   usuário final.

Comment: Não necessariamente todos os elementos, é possível reduzir o escopo da busca realizando uma pré-consulta antes, exemplo: 'var container = document.getElementById("container"); container.querySelectorAll("[data-content]");'